# Handling an alert in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying a display a URL on the first page of the application, but that URL requires a third-party sign in which pops up like an alert dialog.

I tried handling the alert using WebChormeClient. It works fine when I tried with an example from w3Schools, but the same did not work when I tried with my URL. Is there a way to handle a third-party sign in alerts in webview?

Please find the code that I have used:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
mywebview.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mywebview.loadUrl(url);


private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
}
```

I am not supposed give that URL. Imagine that you are loading a URL which asks you for a third-party sign in, in the form of alert, and then it loads the page after successful authentication.

Answer (score -1):

As per your code I thought you don't set following setting Webviewclient and Webcromeclient to enable JavaScript in Webview.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Then you load your HTML page with the following code:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + Your_HTML_Page);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below methods as per your need:

```
mywebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
        return super.onJsPrompt(view, url, message, defaultValue, result);
    }
});
```

#### In Jsresult handling methods

```
result.cancel();
result.confirm();
```

#### In JsPromptResult handling methods

```
result.cancel();
result.confirm();
result.confirm(String msg);
```